# Editing PHP .ini files?

Tags: php

I am looking for a solution where I can edit application configuration data at run time.

Is it possible to access variables within a .ini file and change them like this?

Thanks

**Edit**

My users get their own ini file for their account on the system which stores non sensitive information such as file paths etc defined by the user. If the user wants to change their basepath stored in the .ini file how can I do that?

Comment: it would be quite useless at run time.

Comment: Are you talking about PHP's configuration information that's stored in the "php.ini" file, or application specific information that you're store in a .ini file of your own?

Answer (score 6):

No, but you could use `ini_set` to set vars of php at runtime.

Comment: I failed to mention, but I am not talking about php.ini I am talking about app specific ini files.